# What are the requirements to translate documents?

Tags: usa, translations, uscis

According to the website,

> **If you submit any documents (copies or original documents, if requested) in a foreign language, you must include a full English translation along with a certification from the translator verifying that the translation is complete and accurate, and that they are competent to translate from the foreign language to English.**

Can the petitioner translate the document? What are the requirements to translate the document?

Comment: I don’t have an official source for this but I’d expect that translations should be done by someone other than the applicant. Example: I recently translated a property title deed from Spanish to English for a friend’s husband who was applying for a UK visa.  The guidance was similar to that stated in your question; I followed it and the application was approved.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who certifies that they know both languages well enough can translate. See [8 CFR 103.2(b)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/103.2).

> **(3) Translations**. Any document containing foreign language submitted to USCIS shall be accompanied by a full English language translation which the translator has certified as complete and accurate, and by the translator's certification that he or she is competent to translate from the foreign language into English.

There seem to not be any restriction in the CFR for the petitioner to be the translator. However, IMHO it's best to use translation services - they can provide the certification and usually have very fast turn-around with prepared templates for almost any document you might need translated.